# Replace If statement with ternary operator

Tags: objective-c, c, if-statement, operators, ternary-operator

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to replace the following code with a simpler code, using the ternary operator.

```
if ([self.pesoNota[@"nota"] floatValue] > 0.0) {
        suaNota = [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.pesoNota[@"nota"] floatValue]]];
    }
    else {
        suaNota = @"ND";
    }
    if ([exercicio[@"notaComunidade"] floatValue] > 0.0) {
        notaComunidade = [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[exercicio[@"notaComunidade"] floatValue]]];
    }
    else {
        notaComunidade = @"ND";
    }

    self.notaLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", suaNota, notaComunidade];
```

Something like this:

```
self.notaLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.pesoNota[@"nota"] floatValue]]] ? : @"ND", [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[exercicio[@"notaComunidade"] floatValue]]] ? : @"ND"];
```

The second code doesn't give me the expected result, it returns 0 in case the first expression is false, I want it to return a string.

Anyway, I don't think it is possible to reduce this code, but anyways, it's worth a try since I use this a lot.

Comment: "since I use this a lot" - so why don't you put it into its own function/method?

Comment: Fewer lines != simpler…

Comment: Well thanks, that sure is an option, but the question is more conceptual, I just want to know if it's possible to reduce this code. And for me, fewer lines == simpler. :)

Comment: I didn't include this in my answer because it was not quite what you were asking about, but you have this bit of code that is really unnecessary: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.pesoNota[@"nota"] floatValue]].  You can just use: self.pesoNota[@"nota"] since this is already an NSNumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you use this code a lot you should dedicate a small helper function to it. Second thing, your example is missing conditions and the semantics is completely different from your desired result:

```
self.notaLabel.text = 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", 
    [nf stringFromNumber:
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.pesoNota[@"nota"] floatValue]]] ? 
        /* missing condition */ :
        @"ND", 

    [nf stringFromNumber:
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[exercicio[@"notaComunidade"] floatValue]]] ? 
        /* missing condition */ :
        @"ND"
];
```

It should be something like:

```
self.notaLabel.text = 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@",
  [self.pesoNota[@"nota"] floatValue] > 0.0 ? // condition 
     [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.pesoNota[@"nota"] floatValue]]] // true case
     : @"ND" // false case
  ,
  [exercicio[@"notaComunidade"] floatValue] > 0.0 ? // condition
     [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[exercicio[@"notaComunidade"] floatValue]]] // true case
     : @"ND" // false case
];
```

Which is quite unreadable in any case. I mean, you can declare local variables right to avoid messy code:

```
NSNumber* notaValue = self.pesoNota[@"nota"];
NSNumber* notaComunidade = exercicio[@"notaComunidade"];

self.notaLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@",
  [notaValue floatValue] > 0 ? [nf stringFromNumber:notaValue] : @"ND",
  [notaComunidade floatValue] > 0 ? [nf strungFromNumber:notacomunidadate] : @"ND"
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains duplication you could extract into another method:

```
- (NSString *)floatStringOrNDForNumber:(NSNumber *)number numberFormatter:(NSNumberFormatter *)numberFormatter {
    return ([number floatValue] > 0.0f) ? [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number] : @"ND";
}
```

Then you have a pretty clean, understandable few lines of code:

```
suaNota = [self floatStringOrNDForNumber:self.pesoNota[@"nota"] numberFormatter:nf];
notaComunidade = [self floatStringOrNDForNumber:exercicio[@"notaComunidade"] numberFormatter:nf];
self.notaLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", suaNota, notaComunidade];
```